# Populating DropdownMenu with an array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

Can someone tell me how to populate a dropdown menu with the elements in the array and when someone chooses a certain album like say Closing time after submitting the form it will replace with the 2nd element of the array "in voorraad" 
I have been trying to search for it I can't find anywhere.

Array in php form

```
$album["Closing time"]="in voorraad";
$album["Rumba Azul"]="uit voorraad"; 
$album["Survivor"]="in voorraad";  
$album["Greatest Hits Queen"]="uit voorraad";
$album["3121 Prince"]="in voorraad";
```

The html part I don't know how to query the array in

```
<form action="Albert_verwerken.php" method="post">
<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpading=0>  
<tr> <td>Achgternaam:</td> <td><input type="text" name="achternaam"></td></tr>   
<tr> <td>Voornaam:</td> <td><input type="text" name="voornaam"></td></tr>
<tr> <td>Adres:</td> <td><input type="text" name="adres"></td></tr>
<tr> <td>Postcode:</td> <td><input type="text" name="postcode"></td></tr>
<tr> <td>Plaats:</td> <td><select name="plaats">
<option value="">Kies...</option>
<option value="amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
<option value="rotterdam">Rotterdam</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $html .= "<option value='$key'>$value</key>";
}

echo "<select name="process">$html</select>";
```

where $array is your array.

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

---

and following on you can pick this up in processing as follows:

```
$p = $_POST; //assuming its post

$value = $p['process'];
```

Comment: the array is in the processing form i have an index.php and processing.php the top part is in processing the bottom part is in index

Comment: why not move the array to the index page and just pass the value you need to the processing form?

Comment: hmm if i move it there what codes shuold i use ?
im sorry for the simplistic questions but im in a test right now and i have to pass it it woul mean alot to me if yuo would help me :)

Comment: you can use the same code, just create the <select> part as above then when the form get passed to processing you will have the value. I will update my example as i think its wrong.

Comment: Index:
<php?
$voorraad["Closing time"]="in voorraad";
$voorraad["Rumba Azul"]="uit voorraad";
$voorraad["Survivor"]="in voorraad";
$voorraad["Greatest Hits Queen"]="uit voorraad";
$voorraad["3121 Prince"]="in voorraad";

foreach($voorraad $key=>$value){
    $html .= "<option value='$key'>$value</key>";
}

echo "<select name="process">$html</select>";?>


this should work like this if i add it to the index?